# Sending data from php to ajax (with mysqli_fetch_assoc and json_encode)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm relatively new to programming using php and ajax, so please hear me out.

This is my jQuery/ajax code:

```
function change2(radio){
        section = $('input[type=radio][name=section]:checked').prop('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: './templates/teacherIndex4.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'grade': grade, 'section': section},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if(res.status == "ok") {
                    document.getElementById("listStud").innerHTML = "Test";
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

I have already checked the grade and section variables, and they are okay.
This is my php code:

```
if (isset($_GET['grade']) && isset($_GET['section'])) {
        $grade = $_GET['grade'];
        $section = $_GET['section'];

        $recent_year = (int)date("Y"); 
        $recent_month = (int)date("n"); 
        if ($recent_month < 6){
          $recent_year = $recent_year - 1;
        } 
        $next_year = (int)$recent_year + 1; 
        $schoolyear = "S.Y. " . $recent_year . " - " . $next_year;

        $sy = "select * from schoolyear where schoolYear = '$schoolyear'";
        $syRes = mysqli_query($conn, $sy);
        $schoolyearid  = mysqli_fetch_array($syRes);
        $schoolyear = $schoolyearid['schoolyear_id'];

        $query = "select * from student where schoolyearid_fk = '$schoolyear' and gradeid_fk = '$grade' and sectionid_fk = '$section'";
        $userinfo = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $res = array(); 
        while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)){ 
            $res[] = $line;
        }

        $res['status'] = "ok";
        print json_encode($res);
}
```

My problem is, it returns this in the error function:
[console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC1nu.png)

I have tried changing the dataType to 'text', and it returns an empty response, but in the success function (trying to get res.status returns undefined).

I have also tried `print json_encode($line)` and `echo json_encode($line)`, and it seems to return the info I have been looking for (here: [data with crushed out real names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwB12.png))

Can anybody please help me with this? This is for my solo research and I don't know how to solve this.

**EDIT** - All the codes before the `function change2(radio)` (in the js file):

```
var grade;    
function drop(x){
        y = x.toString();
        id = "id" + y;
        $('#' + id).toggle("slow");
        if ($('#' + y).hasClass('active')){
            $('#' + y).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#' + y).addClass('active');
        }
    }

    function drop2(){
        $('#subhand').toggle("slow");
        if ($('#subhand').hasClass('active')){
            $('#subhand').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#subhand').addClass('active');
        }
    }

    function change(radio) { 
        if (radio.checked && radio.id === "1") {
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='1' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Emerald &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='2' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Jade &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='3' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Ruby &nbsp;";
            grade = 1;
        } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === "2"){
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='4' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Dahlia &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='5' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Kamia &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='6' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Rosal &nbsp;";
            grade = 2;
        } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === "3"){
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='8' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Sodium &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='9' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Potassium &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='7' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Lithium &nbsp;";
            grade = 3;
        } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === "4"){
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='11' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Neutron &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='10' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Electron &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='12' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Proton &nbsp;";
            grade = 4;
        } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === "5"){
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='13' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block A &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='14' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block B &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='15' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block C &nbsp;";
            grade = 5;
        } else if (radio.checked && radio.id === "6"){
            document.getElementById("sections").innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='16' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block A &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='17' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block B &nbsp;<input type='radio' id='18' name='section' onclick='change2(this)'>Block C &nbsp;";
            grade = 6;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2** - Network tab (in dev tools): [Network tab result in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a6hN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Got the solution already. Had to do this:

```
$res = array(); 
   while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)){ 
     $line["full_name"] = json_encode($line["full_name"]); //This line is the solution to the whole thing 
     $res[] = $line;
 }
echo json_encode($res); //echo or print, didn't matter
```

In short, the $line["full_name"] had to be json encoded. Printed out the data I was looking for. (Thank you for those who helped me out with my question!)

Answer (score -1):

You should use echo json_encode($res); print function return Boolean. You are not returning json array from the php. You are returning Boolean variable. This is your problem. Your problem will be solved by using `echo json_encode($res);`  It will return json array.

Comment: Can you share your tables with dummy data ? i will do that and then i send code to you. Add me at  s_kype_ . By screen sharing i will fix your problem. Here is my username raokaleemullah786